# incomplete information from query on pg_views

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a view in my database (`PostgreSQL`) and I would like to see it's code.

I wrote this query:

```
select definition from pg_views where viewname='x'
```

this works most of the time, However in some of the views when the `select` code is long I get at some point `(...)`

for example this is one of the results of query where it shows `(...)`:

```
" SELECT f.selectid,
    a.clientid,
    a.orderid,
    a.clientname,
    c.part,
    c.product,
    c.okey,
    e.contry,
    d.city,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN (b.dateofissue IS NULL) THEN
            CASE
       (...)"
```

This is only part of the code... Why it doesn't show me the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `pg_get_viewdef`, but I suspect you'll have the same issue there. The problem is probably that the *client application* is truncating the returned query.

If you're using PgAdmin-III [this is in the FAQ](http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/support/faq.php#ColTrunc).

If you're using `psql` this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

In pgAdmin III, under Query tool options:

[image]

[pgAdmin Query tool Options](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/options-query_tool.html)