# Query result truncates column width over 255 characters

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using a query that concatenate several columns in one, resulting in a long string, sometimes over 255 characters. On the relevant lines, the string ends up with `(...)` and I don't get the full string.

I have tried to specify the column type as TEXT which is supposed to be a [variable unlimited length](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-character.html), without success:

```
SELECT (table_a.col || table_b.col)::TEXT FROM table_a, table_b ;
```

Any idea on how to get the full string?

Comment: Assuming you are using pgAdmin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828182/incomplete-information-from-query-on-pg-views

Comment: That's it! Client application issue... Thanks much.